# Making toast message on thread

Tags: android, kotlin, toast

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    companion object{
        private lateinit var handlerThread: HandlerThread
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) // binding 객체 생성
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        binding.bTest.setOnClickListener { 
            handlerThread = HandlerThread("Test")
            handlerThread.start()
            Test().start()
        }
    }
    
    inner class Test: Thread(){
        override fun run(){
            Handler(handlerThread.looper).post{
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Testing: ${handlerThread.name}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i tried this code but the toast message doesn't work.
i also tried runOnUiThread, but i think that works only in mainactivity, not seperated thread class.

makes toast message

Comment: 1) why create thread, just show() it? 2) what error you getting on logcat, write in question

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `runOnUiThread` works only in the main activity and cannot be used directly in a separate thread. However, you can achieve your goal by using a `Handler` to post a `Runnable` on the main thread to show the toast message. Here's the modified code to make the toast message work:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    companion object {
        private lateinit var handlerThread: HandlerThread
        private lateinit var handler: Handler
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        handlerThread = HandlerThread("Test")
        handlerThread.start()
        handler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)

        binding.bTest.setOnClickListener {
            Test().start()
        }
    }

    inner class Test : Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            handler.post {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Testing: ${handlerThread.name}",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Quit the handlerThread when the activity is destroyed to avoid any leaks.
        handlerThread.quit()
    }
}
```

**Recommendation:**
Never use UI components on the background thread. Always use the main thread to use a view.